# how to input if condition using a string

Tags: java

i am trying to to make a code from which if a user enters a statement the program will execute the statement given by the user. for example. if a person says ,"print hi stackoverflow", so the program will print "hi stackoverflow". the basis logic is that the compiler will search for keyword such as "print" and will print the complete statement after the word "print".
i was making such function for the if else statement where the code would search the keyword "if" and will enter the condition after the word "if" in the if condition for example if the user enters: "if 3>6, print hi". the compiler will interpret it as.

```
     if(3>6){
 "System.out.println(hi);
 }
```

i tried it using the following code

```
import java.util.*;
class TestIfElse
{
        public static void main(String arg[])
     {
       Scanner input=new Scanner(System.in);
        String cmd=input.nextLine();  // for taking input from the user
       boolean checkString1 =cmd.contains("if ");   // cheaking if the string contains the word if
       if(checkString1==true)  
      {     
       int counter=0;                       
       char[] ifcondition= new char[50];    //declaration of array to extract if condition 
           for(int i=cmd.indexOf("if ")+2,j=0;i<=cmd.length()-1;i++,j++)// copying the string after the word if entered by the user 
         {
              ifcondition[j]= cmd.charAt(i);
             counter ++;    // to check the number of characters in the condition 
             }
            for(int i=0;i<=counter;i++)
            {
                if(ifcondition[i])
                {
                                                                    
                    System.out.println("condition ");
                }
            }
}
```

but the compiler shows "incomparable types: char and boolean", i know it is because we have to enter a boolean value in the if condition and i have entered a string.
But how can i tackle this problem, can someone please help me with it?
or maybe a completely different approach that we can apply to make such code

Comment: Just to better orientate an answer: are you trying to learn how to write parsers from scratch or would using an existing parsers generator (like antlr) be ok for you?

Comment: can you give us one scenario in which you believe this will be true? ifcondition[i]==true

Comment: @Stultuske sorry the "==true", was a typed by mistake while i was trying different ways of doing it. now i have edited it

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca from what i know about parsers they are file from which we can take data. If i am right about the meaning of parser then no, i wont be using parser i will be taking input from the user at the time of execution

Comment: @nischalsharma how is that edit of yours even going to compile? a char is not a boolean statement

Comment: @Stultuske yes it is not compiling . but you asked about ==true condition so i said that it was typed by mistake and now i have removed it

Comment: @Stultuske it won't compile, that's kinda the point of the question. They're asking how to evaluate a string containing a boolean expression as a boolean.

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca some other approach to doing this might also work if you have something in mind

Comment: @user16320675 i edited it now can you try ?

Comment: @nischalsharma are those expression always in the form of `OPERAND1 OPERATOR OPERAND2` or can they be more complex? If it's the former case split the expression into three and go with a switch like `switch (operator) { case "<": return operand1 < operand2; case ">": return operand1 > operand2; }` and so on. If it's the latter then it gets complicated.